Roots of a polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$
I am trying to compute the eigenvalues of the unitary DFT of the symmetric group algebra over $\mathbb{Q}$ where a minimal number of square roots have been adjoined. For $n=3$, $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ and the characteristic polynomial in $K[x]$ is
$$f(x) = x^6 + (-1/(3\sqrt{3}) - 1/2)x^5 + ((-1/(6\sqrt{2}) + 1/6)\sqrt{3} - 1/(3\sqrt{2}) - 1/3)x^4 + ((1/(3\sqrt{2}) + 1/3)\sqrt{3} + 1/(2\sqrt{2}))x^3 + ((-1/(6\sqrt{2}) + 1/6)\sqrt{3} - 1/(3\sqrt{2}) - 1/3)x^2 + (-1/(3\sqrt{3}) - 1/2)x + 1$$
The eigenvalues lie on the unit circle. Using Sage, I compute the splitting field $L$ to be a 192 degree extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ with defining monic polynomial $x^{192} + 192x^{191} + \ldots + 778\ldots448$ where the coefficients are large integers. Over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$, the minimal polynomial for the eigenvalues is degree 24, monic, with rational coefficients:
$$g(x) = x^{24} + 2x^{23} - (1/2)x^{22} - \ldots - (1/2)x^2 + 2 x + 1 $$
Are the roots of this polynomial roots of unity?
EDIT: $[L:K]=|\text{Gal}(L/K)|=48$. The only transitive subgroup of order 48 in $S_6$ is $S_2 \wr S_3$.

The minimal polynomials of the roots of unity over $\mathbb{Q}$ are cyclotomic polynomials, and in particular have integer coefficients (pretty small ones too). You say the minimal polynomial of the roots of $f$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ has rational coefficients; I assume you mean they aren't all integers, in which case the roots can't be roots of unity.
Alternatively, this also follows from the computation of the degree of the splitting field. The fact that $192 \neq 24$ actually means the Galois group is necessarily nonabelian (this is a good exercise, you need to show that if the Galois group is abelian then its order $|G|$ is the number of roots), so the roots are not only not roots of unity but they are not even expressible as sums of roots of unity.

Thanks.. Yes, only 4 coefficients of the minimal polynomial are integers.
